# SOAPUI build with maven failed

Tags: java, maven, soapui

I git clone soapui 5.1.2, installed maven 3.3.1 and as instructed https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui try to build soapui with

```
mvn clean install
```

In the end I got this error in screenshot

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] SoapUI project ..................................... SUCCESS [01:05 min]
    [INFO] SoapUI ............................................. FAILURE [02:16 min]
    [INFO] SoapUI Maven plugin ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] SoapUI installer ................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] SoapUI Maven plugin tester ......................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] SoapUI system test ................................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 03:21 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-23T16:44:23+01:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/217M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project soapui: Could not resolve dependencies
     for project com.smartbear.soapui:soapui:jar:5.2.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find arti
    fact org.sonatype.install4j:i4jruntime:jar:5.1.14 in smartbear-sweden-repository
     (http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
    ch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
    d the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
    lutionException
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :soapui
```

My connectivity is fine. But I can't see org.sonatype.install4j:i4jruntime:jar:5.1.14 in http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/

Why ? Does it mean the editor forget to put it so it's a mistake from them not me doing something wrong ? How to fix this ? Contact the editor ?

Comment: Why are you posting text converted to a graphic? How is your connectivity to wherever the jar is? How is the server where that jar is being hosted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error, the problem is in the [soapui/pom.xml](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/blob/next/soapui/pom.xml). They are referencing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.install4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>i4jruntime</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.14</version>
</dependency>
```

twice, just to be sure I guess. This jar is indeed not available at [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.sonatype.install4j%22).

Their entire project has only one custom repository specified - [their own](http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2) (also mentioned in the error) - and this jar is not there either. Chances are they have this jar in their local artifactory, and just never bothered updating the dependencies.

Keep in mind that Maven is just a tool, and just like any tool, if you use it wrong it will do the wrong things. You could remove the dependency from their pom and see if the project builds, or search the Internet for this jar and manually place it in your local repository.

Comment: thanks, that helps as I'm absolute beginner with maven. It's really a  pity they didn't care more about the quality of their opensource build I followed their instruction and it does not work https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui